# How to fetch multiple twitter user's feed in API 1.1

Tags: android, twitter

I am using twitter latest **REST API v1.1** and **application-only authentication** to fetch 8 users today's feed/status to show in a listView. I was using `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=10&exclude_replies=true&screen_name=UserName` to fetch each user feed. But I don't know how to fetch only today's feed. So I fetched around latest 10 feed by using `&count=10` and filter these based on today's date. But it seems to be a poor way. Also I want to fetch my 8 user's feed together for better performance because fetching 8 user's feed individually is time expensive and not a good way. So

***How can I get a JSON feed of today's tweets of 8 users in one request? What should be the URL?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `statuses/user_timeline` API endpoint only supports getting the tweets for a single user, so if you want to get the tweets for eight users you'll need to make 8 requests.

There is a way around this though...

If you make a Twitter list containing those 8 users, you can make a single request to the [`lists/statuses`](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/create-manage-lists/api-reference/get-lists-statuses) endpoint that will return tweets from all members of the list.

Comment: Thanks fot your answer, Sir! What can I add with the request URL? My 8 users are `elquetzalteco, NuestroDiario, el_Periodico, siglo21gt, prensa_libre, muniguate, EmisorasUnidas, Publinews_GT, lahoragt`. So how can add them with the request URL to get their today's feed? Please add more details. Complete URL would be more appreciable.

Comment: First you need to create a list. You can do this via the API but the easiest way is just to hit the 'Create list' button on the Twitter website - you can find it here: https://twitter.com/<your_twitter_username>/lists. Once you've got a list in place you can make your call with a URL like this: https://api.twitter.com/1/lists/statuses.json?slug=<teamname>&owner_screen_name=<your_twitter_username>&per_page=1&page=1&include_entities=true

Comment: hello Sir I am using application-only oauth which won't require any credentials only a bearer token. But it seems the `lists/status` requires credential. :(

Comment: Sir, can I fetch only today's feed(last 24 hours)?

Comment: You can use the since_id optional parameter to get all tweets since the one you specify, so if you're running this once a day you can get all tweets since the last tweet you retrieved the previous day. The since_id param is described here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/lists/statuses

Answer (score 0):

You can use Search: `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=from%3A[twitter_username_1]+OR+from%3A[twitter_username_2]`

Just make sure you don't go over a certain number of users (15-20), otherwise it returns Bad Request.

For PHP users:

```
$twitter_users = array('katyperry','BarackObama','ladygaga','YouTube');
$search_query = implode("+OR+from%3A", $twitter_users);
$feed_url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=from%3A".$search_query;
```

Comment: From the docs: "Please note that Twitter's search service and, by extension, the Search API is not meant to be an exhaustive source of Tweets. Not all Tweets will be indexed or made available via the search interface."